# Find the area of the rectangle

Tags: mathematics, visual, geometry

The image below shows a half circle, and a rectange **DBFE**. Your task is simply to calculate the area of the rectangle, based on the information given in the image.

[image]

Comment: The solution is very interesting, but I'm afraid I must VTC - this is simply a mathematics exercise, not a puzzle. Interesting, but not a puzzle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If C = E then the area is 18, since both will be at the maximum point of the semicircle and, therefore, 6 is the hypotenuse of a square.
>  [image]
>  If C = A then the area is 18, since then 6 is the long side of the rectangle, and the diameter of the semicircle, and the smaller side of the rectangle will be the radius of the semicircle, that is, 3.
>  [image]
>  If C belongs to the arc between A and the maximum point of the semicircle, it will take values between those, so must be 18.

Another way, with more geometric, then:

> The triangle D-C-Center of the circumference is a right triangle whose hypotenuse is the radius.
>  DB minus radius squared plus DC squared is, therefore, the radius squared. Since DB squared plus DC squared is 6 squared, then DB multiplied by radius is 18. And since the small side of the rectangle is the radius, then the area is 18.
>  [image]
>  Formulas:
>  $(DB-r)^2 + DC^2 = r^2$ (because Center to B and Center to C are radius)
>  $DB^2 + DC^2 = 6^2$ 
>   => $DB^2 - 2DBr + r^2 + DC^2 = r^2$ 
>   => $6^2 - 2DBr = 0$
>   => $DBr = 18$

Comment: Ok, I'm adding the formulas to make it more understandable. Sorry.

Comment: Your answer is also short and nice!!!(+1)

Answer (score 10):

[image]

> Let $DB = a$, $AD = b$. So, $CD = \sqrt{ab}$
> $$$$
> By Pythagoras theorem,
> $$$$
> $6^2 = a^2 + ab = a(a+b)$
> $$$$
>  Also, radius $r = \frac{a+b}{2}$ = breadth of the rectangle.
> $$$$
>  So, Area$$A= a(a+b)/2 = 36/2 = 18$$

---

> ***PROOF*** for $CD = \sqrt{ab}$
> $$$$
> In a semicircle the angle touching the circle at any point from the two ends of the diameter is $90^o$

[image]

> $$AC^2 = b^2 +c ^2$$
> $$6^2 + AC^2 = AB^2$$
> $$6^2 + b^2 +c ^2 = (a+b)^2$$

Also, $6^2 = a^2 + c^2 $

> So, $$a^2 + c^2 + b^2 + c^2 = (a+b)^2 = a^2 +b^2 +2ab$$
> $$c^2 = ab$$
> $$c = \sqrt{ab}$$

Comment: This answer is really cool.

Comment: @Ak19 You're welcome! It's a brilliant answer!

Comment: The proof you provide at the end is known as rot13(Trbzrgevp zrna gurberz) (hiding its name is probably excessive, but it could still be a hint, so...)

Answer (score 2):

My answer:

> As the diameter $d$ of the semicircle is not given,
>  the answer must be the same for all $d \geq 6$.
>
>  This includes $d = 6$, when the area of the rectangle will be
>
>  $ \frac{d^2}{2} = 18$

---

More explanation as requested:

> The question says "based on the information given in the image" where the only numerical information is $6$ the length of the line. Clearly the circle can have a larger diameter than the one shown and there will be a solution for a line length $6$.
>
>  Also for smaller ones, the smallest of which has diameter $6$, in which case the line is on the horizontal diameter. Here, the rectangle exactly encloses the semicircle, and therefore has dimensions $6 \times 3$.
>
>  As no information was given as to the diameter, the answer (if there is an answer) must be $18$ for **all** possible semicircles, including the special case.
>
>  [image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya I have extended the answer.

Comment: Could not the answer be such that it depended on the radio? It would still be a valid answer, and would continue to fit the special cases, but it would not always be exactly the value of any of the special cases.

Comment: @Hermes if that were true, then the question did not contain enough information to answer it. The algebraic solution has already been posted, where the radius $r$ cancels out.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. As the question is posed, I would say the answer is correct.

Comment: @Hermes after all this is a puzzle site, not a mathematics site! I rather like puzzles which apparently have insufficient information.